# Session State being cleared or lost after one AJAX call to .NET CORE 2.1 application hosted on IIS server

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, session-state

I have run into this problem for which I have been scratching my head for hours now.

The problem: The Session State that I create on `Login` gets mysteriously cleared or lost after calling an `API` controller which is also in .NET CORE 2.1. This happens when I call a `API` method that looks like:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "AdminViewPolicy")]
    [HttpGet("GetAllUsersId")]
    public IActionResult GetAllUsersId()
    {
        var user = _userService.GetAllUsersId();
        return Ok(new
        {
            data = user
        });
    }
```

The roles and other aspects of this method are working correctly. This is how I call this action method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.someworkingwebsite.com/api/Users/GetAllUsersId",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {},
    credentials: 'include',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", window.localStorage.getItem("authToken"));
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html = [];
        for (var i in data["data"]) {
            var id = data["data"][i]["fullName"] + "###" + data["data"][i]["uuid"] + "###" + data["data"][i]["id"];
            //var id = data["data"][i]["uuid"] + "###" + data["data"][i]["id"];
            html.push(id);
        }
        /*initiate the autocomplete function on the "searchInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("searchInput"), html);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Error" + data);
    },
});
```

My Startup.cs configuration for `API` project looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddCors();
           services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
               {
                   // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                   options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
               });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelAttribute));

            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      //Other code omitted for brevity 
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();

            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
    }
```

My client side filter for checking `Session` looks like:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (Context.Current.Session == null || !Context.Current.Session.TryGetValue("UserID", out byte[] val))
    {
        context.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Pages",
                action = "SessionTimeout"
            }));
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

The part where it gets tricky. When I call the AJAX function from my `View`, the AJAX successfully calls the `API` method and gets the required data needed, but also with that the AJAX call clears my session off somehow because as soon I navigate to some other page or make form submission, the `SessionTimeout` attribute shown above gets called and I am kicked out of the system.

I have checked all Console logs, Network requests, Application storage on my web browser and I could not find the culprit. I also checked the logic in my both the API and Client to see if somehow I was doing this major blunder but I could not find anything suggestive of this.

Since the `API` and the Client are hosted on a IIS server, I thought maybe that darn environment could be doing something but nope, I could not find anyone to blame there also.

So after a lot of here and there's, I finally decided to ask the pro's. It would be great if someone could help me and `hopefully` resolve this issue of mine.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Sounds like you might have Cookies turned off in the web browser. The HTTP Response to your API request should include a [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header with name, value, domain, etc. strings. The subsequent HTTP Requests from your browser to the same site should include a [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header with a ;-delimited list of name=value pairs for cookies belonging to that domain.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the comment but I am generating the `Session` on my Client side and the only thing that I get from the server is my `Token` that is generated on successful authorization. The Client side has a `Session` for managing some variables and I use those when I wanted to request for something from the `API` via headers. I am not defining any explicit `Cookie`

Comment: By Token I assume you mean JWT? There's nothing in your Configure/ConfigureServices code to suggest that you are binding JSON Web Token authentication to the server-side Sessions. Therefore each request will be creating a new server-side Session.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have omitted that because of how I am generating my token. Is there no way to enforce that new Session is not opened on the server via AJAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so regarding this issue, the solution that I've found is to change the session cookie name for each application which are interacting with each other.

`In Startup / Configure()`, change the cookie name of the application :

```
app.UseSession(new SessionOptions() { Cookie = new CookieBuilder() { Name = ".AspNetCore.Session.MyApp1"}});
```

I do not thoroughly know why this was happening in the first place. I would really appreciate if someone could shed more light on this issue.

Thanks and I hope this helps someone who is facing a similar issue.

Comment: I'm quite shocked that this is the solution, but it is.  And still in .Net Core 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I hadn't noticed that you were on ASP.NET Core 2.1. Version 2.1 and later have GDPR-related changes that affect the default behavior of the `.AspNetCore.Session` cookie, as in: it doesn't generate one by default.

Assuming your application doesn't run afoul of GDPR you can enable the previous Cookie-Session mapping behavior with two changes to your ConfigureServices() method.

The first, which you already have, is to change `CookiePolicyOptions.CheckConsentNeed` from `true` to `false` (which you already do):

```cs
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

The second is to mark the session cookie as Essential:

```cs
    services.AddSession(opts => 
    {
        opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
    });
```

Read up more about this in [Why isn't my session state working in ASP.NET Core? Session state, GDPR, and non-essential cookies](https://andrewlock.net/session-state-gdpr-and-non-essential-cookies/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately the error still remains. I am still being signed out after the `AJAX` call.

Comment: And this is ONLY happening when I a `AJAX` call to the `API`. Using `Form` works fine.